# Localize UITabBarItem in RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift, uitabbaritem

How can I localize UITabBarItem and add set images for selected and unselected case in RxSwift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use Rx for something like this. Just use `NSLocalizedString(_:comment:)`

Comment: I tried, but It is not changing. I am using MVVM+Coordinator.

Comment: The architecture is irrelevant. Any basic tutorial about how to localize your app will be fine. For example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/250-internationalizing-your-ios-app-getting-started